# How to add @odata.nextLink in graph api request

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph, typescript, azure-ad-graph-api

I've a service to get all users from Azure AD.

```
public getAllUsers(): Promise<Array<Person>> {
    return graph
      .users
      .select("displayName", "accountEnabled")
      .top(25)
      .expand("manager")
      .get()
      .then((results) => {
        return results.map((item: any) => {
          return {
            displayName: item.displayName,
            accountEnabled: item.accountEnabled,
            manager: item.manager ? item.manager.displayName : ''
          };
        });
      });
  }
```

```
export class Person {
  public displayName: string;
  public accountEnabled: number;
  public manager: any;
}
```

[image: Results]

I have over 200 users. I use **.top** to get 25 users per request. And in the response I receive a link to the next request **'@odata.nextLink'**.
[image: Query response]

Can you please tell me how can I request this link again while it is coming? And write the results to a common array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do recursive call based on next link then you should use `paged` method which can give necessary details related to page.

Try below code, it should work (**Important:** I have created sample using `pnpjs` version `3.17.0`, and if you are using older version of `pnpjs` then you might need to adapt as per older documentation)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IHelloWorldProps } from './IHelloWorldProps';

import { GraphFI, graphfi, SPFx as graphSPFx, IPagedResult } from "@pnp/graph";
import '@pnp/graph/presets/all';
export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component<IHelloWorldProps, {}> {
  private graph: GraphFI;

  constructor(props: IHelloWorldProps) {
    super(props);

    this.graph = graphfi().using(graphSPFx(this.props.context));

  }

  async componentDidMount() {

    let allUsers: any[] = new Array<any>();
    let result: IPagedResult = null;    
    do {

      if (result == null) {
        result = await this.graph
          .users
          .select("displayName", "accountEnabled")
          .top(100)
          .expand("manager").paged();
      }
      else if (result.hasNext) {
        result = await result.next();
      }
      allUsers.push(...(result.value as any[]))
      console.log('DEMO', result);
      if (!result.hasNext) {
        break;
      }
    }
    while (true)

    console.log('DEMO', allUsers);

  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IHelloWorldProps> {


    return (
      <div>Sample Web Part</div>
    );
  }
}
```

See output below:

[image]

Comment: @Propool did this solution work for you?